# Strictly typed pointers in C (hypothetically)

Tags: c, pointers

Here's a question I got in an exam today:

In C, suppose the pointers are strictly typed (ie, a pointer to an int cannot be used to point to a char). Does this reduce its expressive power? If no, why and how would you compensate for this limitation? If yes, how? And what more constructs would you have to add to "equalize" the loss of expressive power of C?

Some additional details:

- By reduced expressive power, I think it means this: you will not be able to create certain programs that you could earlier.
- Strictly typed pointers means you cannot do something like: `int x = 5; int *p = &x; char *temp = (char*)p;`
- This includes `(void*)` conversions

I've included my answer below as well.

Comment: The question is not clear. In C language all pointer types *are* strictly typed already, and has always been since the first C89/90. You cannot initialize/assign an `int *` pointer to point to a `char` object (unless you force this operation through an explicit type cast). The only pointer type in C that can be made to point to other data types without an explicit cast is `void *`. The only reason you can sometimes do it without a cast in practical code is that some C compilers by default follow very loose enforcement policies.

Comment: So, what is the question about? Outlawing explicit casts? The person asking the question was simply unaware of the fact that C is already strictly typed (in the above sense)? Or something else? What exactly is meant by "strictly typed"?

Comment: Fixed the question. Strictly typed in the sense that a char pointer can only point to a character. Even explicit type casts cannot make it point to int* or double*.

Comment: Great, but (referring to the updated question) note that things like `int *p = 5` are *already* illegal in C. They have been illegal since C89/90. You need a cast (as in `int *p = (int *) 5`) for that to become legal C. If your C compiler allows `int *p = 5`, it means that your C compiler has overly relaxed error checking. This happens pretty often (for compatibility with legacy pre-standard code), but nevertheless `int *p = 5` is not allowed in standard C already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does that also mean no more `void*`? If so, then yes: C's expressiveness would be limited, as `malloc` would be impossible to implement. You'd need to add a new, typed, free store allocation mechanism in the spirit of C++ `new`.

<s>(Or, no: C would still be Turing-complete. But I don't think that's what's meant here.)</s>

Actually, C isn't even Turing-complete; see comments below.

Comment: A note on the Turing-completeness of C: a Turing machine is a finite-state controller with an infinite tape. Strictly, only with such a tape and an interface with read, write, step left and step right instructions, C is Turing-complete. `malloc` doesn't make the difference, because no number of calls to it can allocate an infinite amount of memory (`sizeof(void *)` is a constant).

Comment: A single C implementation is not Turing-complete, but a family of C implementations where you recompile the program in a new implementation with increased type sizes and rerun it whenever the program runs out of memory is Turing-complete. This is due to Representation of Types.

Comment: Note that "runs out of memory" has a *formal* meaning in the language due to the fact that an array of `sizeof(void *)` `unsigned char`s can hold at most `(UCHAR_MAX+1)^sizeof(void *)` possible pointer values.

Comment: @R..: yes, so the C language is in a certain sense Turing-complete, but every implementation is finite-state unless you add an interface to infinite memory.

Comment: The language is not even Turing complete; it specifies an implementation that defines bounds that prevent it from being Turing-complete. You need an infinite family of C implementations with progressively larger pointer types to be Turing-complete.

Comment: @R..: yes, that's what I meant by *in a certain sense*. On second thought, this is indeed not Turing-completeness, since it requires an infinite number of implementations.

Comment: @R..: if you read the ISO specification of `fseek` carefully, it turns out C can use an unbounded tape represented as a binary stream (`FILE*`).

Comment: @larsmans: With repeated relative seeks? Perhaps an implementation could support this, but POSIX conformant implementations explicitly cannot (at least not for "regular files") since they're required to give `EOVERFLOW` when the resulting position would not fit in `off_t`.

Comment: @R..: but an unbounded tape would not be a regular file, it would be a char device :)

Answer (score 2):

It might actually increase C's expressiveness. C is one of the few languages for which any given implementation is specified **not to be turing complete**. The Representation of Types in the standard specifies all types as being represented as an overlaid array of `char`, meaning all types and the total data available to the program (the space of all possible pointers, all possible filenames, and all possible file offsets, etc.) is finitely bounded, and therefore the computation model of C is a **finite state machine**.

If you removed the requirement that pointers be represented as `char [sizeof (pointer type)]` then the formally-specified language could in principle deal with an infinite amount of data, and it would be Turing-complete.

Comment: C is not turing complete?! By your argument, every language in the world isn't! Can you point me to some article/book that deals with this?

Comment: @Utkarsh: you can verify this for yourself. `void*` has a constant size in any C implementation, so there's a maximum to the amount of memory a C program can address; every data object and every function has an address that can be converted to `void*`. (This matches the fact that practical computers are finite-state machines. It is not necessarily true for other languages.)

Comment: Indeed. You could *imagine* a machine with a "two-dimensional tape" that could, at each "memory location" in one dimension, hold a unbounded pointer/reference value. Most languages could be implemented on such a machine to be Turing-complete. However, due to the *specification* of the Representation of Types in the C standard, this is not possible for C. The number of possible pointers is bound by the fact that they are represented as an array of bytes (`char`). The same applies to file names and file offsets, the only other ways of addressing data in C.

Answer (score 1):

Well its a very subjective question.  Couple that with the fact I've no idea what "expressive power" is ;)

Still not being able to cast between pointer types is a big limitation in my head.  It seems that when using Java mapping a char array (Coming from something like a network socket for example) to a class is incredibly annoying.  The ability to just cast it and re-interpret the memory is incredibly useful and allows for significant optimisations in processing random blocks of memory.

How would you get round these limitations?  Perhaps implement a "cast" function or perhaps just a templated memcpy function that can re-interpret the memory would be a huge bonus for optimisation and, for people like me, productivity.  It might even be a plan to allow some sort of class "id" to be included in the byte stream so that you know that it can be re-interpreted as a specific class.

The downside to having this power is that it allows you to interpret data in completely the wrong way.  This can cause very nasty bugs.

Answer (score 1):

This question is similar to asking what useful/valid uses of pointer casts are. Here are a few:

Without pointer casts, you must have several versions of `memcpy`, `memmove`, `malloc` as these all require pointer conversions to be implemented and used. In the case of `malloc`, allocating memory for user-defined `struct`s becomes impossible.

In a slightly different category, you cannot implement a polymorphic `qsort` (the one provided by the standard library sorts an array of `void*` and can effectively be used to sort arrays of various kinds of pointers).

As to what kind of feature would allow to regain expressive power, a type system that recognizes polymorphism so that you do not have to encode it with unsafe pointer casts would be a great step. [Languages of the ML family](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ML_%28programming_language%29) have had this kind of type system for a long time, and if you are familiar with [Java's generics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java), they follow the same line of thinking.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it reduces its expressive power - you still are able to write a Turing machine interpreter, meaning it's Turing complete. See for example this [code golf thread](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/84/interpret-brainfuck).

If you mean expressive power in terms of user convenience, then it definitely limits C a lot because the memory allocation mechanism (malloc & co.) would have to be changed.

Comment: Turing completeness is not only a useless measurement for how useful a language really is, OP propably means something different by "expressiveness".

Comment: @delnan: True, but it's difficult to say what exactly he means. And Turing completeness is closest to the common meaning of expressive power.

Comment: Edited the question, I added what I interpreted as expressive power.

Answer (score 0):

> In C, suppose the pointers are
>   strictly typed (ie, a pointer to an
>   int cannot be used to point to a
>   char).

Advocating strict pointer typing in C completely loses the plot, which is that it's just a portable shorthand for assembly language.  You're *supposed* to be able to shoot yourself in the foot and a good developer will be smart enough not to.

Comment: True, but that's what the question was.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a way to get around the limitation of not being able to typecast between various types. You could use a union:

```
union alltypepointers  
{  
    char* c,  
    short* s,
    int* i,  
    float* f,
    double* d,
    ...
};
```

All pointers are the same size, so if you change one, you can read it as any other type. You could do arithmetic on these pointers too:

```
int variable = 0x2345;
alltypepointers p;
p.i = &variable;
char *temp = p.c;
p.c++;
int newint=*p.i;
```

So, you can still do everything you could do earlier => there's no decrease in expressive power.

Comment: C does not specify that the representation of different pointer types is the same. This code has UB. Nor does it specify that you can access data via the wrong pointer type, except `char` types.

Comment: @R. UB? Till now I assumed a pointer was just a 32/64bit number. Should be the same, regardless of the type.

Comment: As an example, many historical machines could only address words, not bytes. Therefore, `char` and `void` pointers were larger, and included an additional byte offset within the word that the generated code would use to extract the desired byte.

Comment: @R: I didn't downvote your answer (in fact, its +1). Can you point me to some article/book/specification/something where I can read about this?

Comment: More recently, x86-16 could have different-sized pointers for functions than for data.

Comment: @dan04: C already completely disallows conversion between function and data pointers, even `void *`. `void (*)()` is the closest thing to a generic function pointer. C requires casts between any function pointer types to preserve the value of the pointer. On the other hand, POSIX requires them to all have the same representation.

Comment: Even apart from R..'s objection, you can never enumerate all `struct` pointers. I'm still not sure what kind of expressiveness your teacher was after, but C without `struct` pointers would be very awkward.

Comment: @larsmans You could add whatever structs you're using. And I'm not sure if I agree with R.'s comment. Ultimately, every single pointer would be the same size. They'd point to a word, and the compiler/instruction would extract the required byte from that word (based on the offset specified). So your pointer is the thing without the "offset" part.

Comment: @Utkarsh: you're confusing the C concept of a pointer with the underlying concept of a memory address. Also, if you have to manually redefine this structure for every program to fit its `struct`s, that's still awkward.

Comment: @larsmans: How are the two different? Is it this: A certain implementation of C could use the standard memory address as char pointer. But another implementation could swap a few bits around for the same pointer? Agreed, the `struct` thing is awkward, but at least there's a way to get things done.

Comment: @Utkarsh: that's a possibility, but the difference between pointers and addresses is also apparent on typical systems where `char*` and `int*` have the same representation. Adding 1 to the memory address of an `int` would yield the next byte in the `int`, but adding 1 to an `int*` yields a pointer to the next `int` (e.g. in an array), so it really adds `sizeof(int)` to the memory address stored in the pointer.

Comment: Ah this is confusing! The notion of pointers that I've had for years is wrong! And I can't understand why >.<

Answer (score -3):

```
(someType *)((void *)somePtr)
```

that contruction allow you to convert any pointer to (someType *).

Comment: Presumably this would be disallowed too, otherwise the question is somewhat trivial.

Comment: -1: That's not what the question is about. The OP asks what would happen if this were disallowed.

Comment: disallowed convertation from (anotherType *) to (someType *), but convertation (anyType *) to (void *) and (void *) to (anyType *) is guaranteed by standart

Comment: You are right. But the OP asks what would happen if any casts weren't possible in C, regardless of what the current standard says.